# Apply an relation to an array in standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two big-query tables.  Table 1 has schema `{id:String, colors:Array[String]}` and looks like

```
| id   | colors                      |
|------|-----------------------------|
| id_1 | ["blue", "green", "orange"] |
| id_2 | ["red" , "blue", "green" ]  |
| ...  | ....                        |
```

and Table 2 relates colors to numbers with schema `{color:String, number:Int}` and looks like

```
| color | number |
|-------|--------|
| "blue"| 0      |
| "red" | 1      |
| ...   | ...    |
```

I want to generate a table that looks like

```
| id | numbers |
|----|---------|
|id_1| [0,3,4] |
|id_2| [1,0,3] |
| ...|...      |
```

obtained by mapping each color in table 1 to its corresponding number.  The only solution I could come up with is

```sql
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(number) AS numbers
FROM (table_1 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(table_1.colors) as color) JOIN table_2 USING(color) 
GROUP BY email
```

but this takes super long (perhaps cuz of the cross-join)

Comment: Your query looks correct.  The `cross join` is fine.  You probably have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also phrase this as:

```
SELECT email,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(number) AS numbers
        FROM UNNEST(table_1.colors) color JOIN 
             table_2
        USING (color) 
       ) as colors
FROM table_1;
```

I'm not sure if the "local" aggregation on each row will work better than the "overall" aggregation in BigQuery.  But this is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT number FROM table_1.colors color 
    JOIN `project.dataset.table_2` USING (color) 
  ) AS numbers
FROM `project.dataset.table_1` table_1
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_1` AS (
  SELECT 'id_1' id, ["blue", "green", "orange"] colors UNION ALL
  SELECT 'id_2', ["red" , "blue", "green" ] 
), `project.dataset.table_2` AS (
  SELECT 'blue' color, 0 number UNION ALL
  SELECT 'red', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'green', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 4
)
SELECT id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT number FROM table_1.colors color 
    JOIN `project.dataset.table_2` USING (color) 
  ) AS numbers
FROM `project.dataset.table_1` table_1
```

with result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this:

```
select id, array_agg(number) as numbers from (
  select id, c, t2.number from table_1 t1, unnest(t1.colors) c
  join table_2 t2 on c = t2.color
)
group by 1
```